# List button in partner community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

We are using the new partner central template and have a page that is using recordList to pull in a list view. The list view layout has the standard new button to create a new record. I trying to implement a custom new button that can do one of the following. Either open a lightning component bundle into a window to create a new record. Or, the custom new button redirects to a new lightning page where I can drop the lightning component bundle into the new lightning page. Is there a way to do this? I'm new to lightning and haven't been able to get the button to do either. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to remember that Lightning pages are single page apps. The only way to redirect to a "new page" from a list view of an object, is to change objects or go to a record view. A component, can open within the existing view by inserting elements into the existing DOM. That's what happens when the standard "new" button is executed.

Replacing or enhancing the functionality of that button, will do the same thing; insert the new elements contained in your component bundle into the Window DOM. In essence, you want to create a new component that is a "composite" of elements. One of those elements would be the button component that causes it to execute. Once pressed, it would "call" or cause your lightning component bundle to open on your existing page.

When designing Lightning components, its best to think of creating many functional blocks or elements that you combine as needed to create more complex functionality. Each block element extends and combines with the functionality of other components, interacting with them in ways to achieve the desired functionality you ultimately desire.

I'd encourage you to go through the many Lightning Design System and Lightning component modules as you can on [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules) and also review the documentation in depth for both [Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm) and the [LDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/).